# Translate Ruby regex into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I've got such a regex in ruby on rails

```
/\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i
```

I'd like to use same email validation logic in front end.

I've tried to use the `.inspect` method in the `irb` console, it doesn't seem to return a js valid regular expression.

As far as I understand `\A` is a `^`, `\Z` is a `$`. `[-a-z0-9]` probably translates to `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. Not sure about the rest.

I've tried to look for an online converter too, couldn't find one. Answers in other similar topics in SO didn't work.

What's the easiest way to translate such regex from ruby into javascript?

Comment: Did you try to use it as is in javascript? What's the result>?

Comment: It should translate about 1 to 1, seems like you already pointed out some conversions except that `[-a-z0-9]` should remain unchanged. It matches any lower-case letter, a digit, or the dash (-). The dash has no special meaning at the start of a character class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by Daniel in the comment it should just translate one to one, I incorrectly assumed that `[-a-z0-9]` should be replaced.

Ruby version:

```
/\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i
```

JavaScript version:

```
/^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/
```

Some tests:

```
/^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i.test("test@email.com"); // true
/^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i.test("test@emailcom");  // false
/^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i.test("testemail.com");  // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [this](http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/ruby/2011/11/18/convert-ruby-regexp-to-javascript-regex.html)?

```
class Regexp
  def to_javascript
    Regexp.new(inspect.sub('\\A','^').sub('\\Z','$').sub('\\z','$').sub(/^\//,'').sub(/\/[a-z]*$/,'').gsub(/\(\?#.+\)/, '').gsub(/\(\?-\w+:/,'('), self.options).inspect
  end
end
```

When you render it to the client simply instantiate a new `RegExp` object with the resulting string:

```
new RegExp(regexpStringFromRuby);
```

Check the [client_side_validations](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/tree/master) gem. It might be what you need.

Comment: I don't understand, should I create a `Regexp` class with the method defined above? Another thing I don't get, why the differet class names `Rexexp` vs. `RegExp`?